# Is there a way to hide non-custom labels from ms chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I have nice MS Chart graph with property

```
 chart1.Series["Series1"].IsXValueIndexed=true;
```

But in X-Axis I get index values because I change AxisX.Maximum during runtime.
[image: What I get as result]

When I set

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].IsXValueIndexed=false;
```

I get X-Axis without index-labels, but during runtime it shifts and I get X-Axis without labels.[image]

Is there way to make labels shown without index-labels?

My function to get datapoint

```
private DataPoint GetDataPoint(string xValue,double yHigh,double yLow,double yOpen,double yClose)
    {
        DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint(0, new double[] {yHigh, yLow, yOpen, yClose})
        {
            Color = (yClose - yOpen > 0) ? _bullBarColor : _bearBarColor,
            AxisLabel = xValue
        };

        return dataPoint;
    }
```

where xValue is like "15.10.1990"

Comment: Um, what labels do you want to show? You ask for hiding and then for showing? You can have regular ones __or__ custom ones __or__ none. The 1st graph looks like you are using custom labels, right?

Comment: Right. I try to find way to show only X-Labels where data exist. Without "26","31","36" in first screen.

Comment: So, are you actually using `CustomLabels` ?? - The problem with CustomLabels is tht they depend on the X-values for their positioning. The recommended way is to add the DataPoints with __valid__ numeric (or datetime) values. Then you can rely on them to always stick to the datapoints. If you don't do that you can still make the series indexed, and that will create indexed x-values. The second snapshot probably doesn't hide your lables; they just are not in view!

Comment: No, in first screen I used non-custom string labels, using `dataPoints[i].AxisLabel` property. But if values are indexed labels are always in view!

Comment: Please showl us the code that adds the DataPoints. Especially the type and value of the x-values are of interest. - Usually the reular labels will go over the full axis at the interval you set. So they will not stop where the charts is empty. For this you would need `CustomLabels`..

Comment: Added function to post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114953/discussion-between-taw-and-vladislav-vazhenin).